# Differentiating a cubed root?

Tags: calculus

True/false: As a fraction, the cube root of 63 is about 191/48 (differentials question).

Am I supposed to solve this by differentiating $63^{1/3}$? So, 63 times 1/3$^{-2/3}$? So, it's false?

Comment: As a fraction, the third root of $63$ is about $8/2$.

Comment: Perhaps it helps to explain the context of the question, i.e., what did you learn in the chapter? One way to solve this would be with Newton's method, which includes differentiation of the function $x^{\frac{1}{3}}$ around the point $x=63$.

Comment: $\frac{191}{48} = 4-\frac1{48}$, so by the binomial theorem $(\frac{191}{48})^3 = 64 - 3\cdot\frac{16}{48} + 3\cdot\frac{4}{48^2} - \frac{1}{48^3}$. The first two terms alone are right, and the last two are negligible.

Comment: But what you're _probably_ supposed to do with a calculus tag is to set $f(x)=x^3$ and then approximate $f(4-\frac1{48})$ as $f(4)-\frac1{48}f'(4)$. Alternatively, set $g(x)=\sqrt[3]x$ and see that $g'(x)=\frac{1}{3g(x)^2}$, and then approximate $g(63)\approx g(64)-g'(64)$.

Comment: "Differentiating $63^{1/3}$" makes no sense, though -- you can't differentiate something that has no variable in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine you are meant to notice that $64=4^3$ and hence to say that the cube root is $4\left(1-\frac{1}{64}\right)^{1/3}$. You take $(1-x)^{1/3}=1-\frac{x}{3}+O(x^2)$, so the root is about $4-\frac{1}{48}=\frac{191}{48}$